# Литература по эффективному использованию Python

Tags: python, производительность, jit

Крис Касперски на форуме RSDN как-то [написал](https://rsdn.org/forum/philosophy/5505259) про эффективное использование Python и про то, что в некоторых случаях он может обогнать компилятор Си по производительности благодаря JIT-компиляции. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где почитать об эффективном применении Python?

И вообще, что почитать, чтобы эффективно использовать JIT?

Comment: Все известные мне попытки впихнуть JIT в питон не давали какого-либо значительного прироста производительности

Comment: @andreymal, а где JIT используется эффективно? Java?